# add event to all labels in form

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add click,mouseleave and mouseenter event to all labels in the form using code below. But  i call the addeventtoalllabels on form_load but it wont add event to labels.

```
  public void setColor()
        {
            if (clickedLabel != default(Label))
                clickedLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            //Resetting clicked label because another (or the same) was just clicked.
        }
        void addeventtoalllabels()
        {
            foreach (Label c in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
            {
                try
                {
                    c.Click += (sender, e) => {
                        setColor(); 
                        Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
                        clickedLabel = theLabel;
                    };
                    c.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
                        if (theLabel != clickedLabel)
                            theLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    };

                    c.MouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
                        if (theLabel != clickedLabel)
                            theLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                    };
                        }
                catch { }


            }

        }
```

Comment: Never use an empty try-catch.  What happens when you debug this?  Are the labels in panels?

Comment: It can only modify the labels that are on the form.  Not, say, any labels that are on a panel.  The natural way to write this code is to make it recursive, call it again with c.Controls as the argument.

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu I've  called it after initialisecomponent and form_load

Comment: It works fine for me. Are these labels in some other container control? You are only iterating over `this.Controls`.

Comment: If you really want all of the `Label` controls in your form to have the same behavior, it is probably better to create a `Label` subclass and use that in your UI. See first answer of marked duplicate. If you don't want to do that, then you need to recursively search your form's controls for controls of the desired type (i.e. `Label`) and add the event handlers on each. See second answer of marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that some of your labels are inside other container controls, so they aren't getting iterated over when you do `this.Controls.OfType<Label>()` (all `Control` objects have a `Controls` collection).

One way to work around this is to recursively look through all the controls' `Controls` collections so you can find the child `Label` objects that belong to other container controls.

Below are 3 methods:

1. `AddEventsToLabel` takes in a `Label` control and adds events to it.
2. `AddEventsToChildLabels` takes in a `Control` argument and checks to see if it's a `Label`. If it is, it passes it to the method in #1 above. Otherwise, it recursively calls itself for each child control of the one that was passed in.
3. `AddEventsToAllLabels` is used to kick off the process - this method calls the method in #2 above, passing in the `Form` itself as the parent control (`this`).

This way we end up iterating over every control on the form, including all those inside other container controls:

```
private void AddEventsToAllLabels()
{
    AddEventsToChildLabels(this);
}

private void AddEventsToChildLabels(Control parent)
{
    if (parent is Label)
    {
        AddEventsToLabel(parent as Label);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            AddEventsToChildLabels(control);
        }
    }
}

private void AddEventsToLabel(Label label)
{
    label.Click += (sender, e) => {
        SetColor();
        Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
        clickedLabel = theLabel;
    };

    label.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
        if (theLabel != clickedLabel) theLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
    };

    label.MouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
        if (theLabel != clickedLabel) theLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

    };
}
```

Note that it might be better to first ***remove*** the event handler before adding it, in case this method gets called more than once. Otherwise, if you hook the same event hander to the same event more than once, each time that event is raised, the handler will execute the number of times that it was added.

For example:

```
private void AddEventsToLabel(Label label)
{
    label.Click -= LabelClick;
    label.MouseEnter -= LabelMouseEnter;
    label.MouseLeave -= LabelMouseLeave;

    label.Click += LabelClick;
    label.MouseEnter += LabelMouseEnter;
    label.MouseLeave += LabelMouseLeave;
}

private void LabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetColor();
    Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
    clickedLabel = theLabel;
}

private void LabelMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
    if (theLabel != clickedLabel) theLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void LabelMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label theLabel = (Label)sender;
    if (theLabel != clickedLabel) theLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```